# 'One health' although uncountable

Tags: word-usage

I came across one sentence that puzzled me: 'Look after yourself because you only have one health.'

I thought that 'health' was an uncountable word, so why is 'one' used here?

I know you cannot say 'two healths'.

Comment: A way of saying, "Once you lose your health, there's no second chance."

Comment: The quote is ungrammatical. I agree with @Kris about the concept they're trying to convey - but it's not a correct use of English.

Comment: English is funny like that. You can order "a water and a coke" at restaurants without asserting that *water* in that sense is otherwise countable. In the case of your quote, consider it poetic license.

Comment: A waiter might say "two waters, three Cokes and a coffee".

Comment: You don't give the context; 'health' is used as a count noun in some games, eg "I had three magic and two health". But it is more likely a play on 'You only have one life', as Lawrence says. Ungrammatical or extragrammatical (ie pushing it but  acceptable) ... that's the question.

Comment: I can't see any grounds for saying the cited usage is "ungrammatical" (how is it any different to common-as-muck *You've only got one life* or *You've only got one body*?). It's just unlikely / unusual / non-idiomatic (but not really even that, if we allow that it's effectively "riffing off" those alternatives).

Comment: @Lawrence "A water" is short for "A (serving / bottle / glass / whatever) of water" -- it's grammatical when parsed with the elision recognized.

Comment: Also @MichaelHarvey There was an identical discussion earlier on this site, too.